# How import modules in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use this module in my haskell code: (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH-1.0.0/docs/Data-String-Utils.html) to use the function "replace" - However, when I try this code:
`import Data.String.Utils`
Haskell tells me there is no such module.

I've installed cabal and stack to do stack build and cabal build

Comment: Can you share your `.cabal` file?

Comment: I have found the answer: I have not added dependency in my package.yaml file